# How from extensions popup repeatedly running a script inserted into the web site (injection from chrome extensions)

Tags: javascript

I use the **manifest** (V3) to insert the script into the website

```css
{
  "name": "GpxNaMapy",
  "description": "example",
  "version": "111",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {"service_worker": "background.js"},
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "webRequest"],
"action": {
  "default_popup": "popupGPX.html"
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://*.gpxmapy.cz/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
}],
"web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": ["inject.js"],
    "matches": ["https://*.gpxmapy.cz/*"]
}]
}
```

**content.js** will inject inject.js into the site and inject.js will run

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var s = document.createElement("script")
  s.setAttribute("id", "GpxNaMapy")
  s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("inject.js")
  document.body.appendChild(s)
}
```

**inject.js** has become part of the page and its function myFunc1 is visible in list console.log(window) and the function has access to all other scripts of the site!

```js
function myFunc1(a) {
  console.log(window)
  alert(a)
}

myFunc1("OK, script injected")
```

**But now I need to repeatedly run this custom embedded function myFunc1() from the extensions popup window. According to the following, it is not possible**

**popupGPX.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <button id="example">example</button>
    <script src="popupGPX.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popupGPX.js**

```js
let button = document.getElementById("example")

button.addEventListener("click", async () => {

  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: script1,
    args: ["example Hello"]
  });
});

function script1(a) {
  console.log(window)
  alert(a)
  window.myFunc1(a) //error
};
```

script1() is running in the background of the website (alert "example Hello" is displayed), but there are no other scripts in the console "window", not even my embedded one, so it cannot be run.

How to do it?

(for English I use Google Translate...)